# Delete rows that not in subquery - ends with NHibernate.QueryException:

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I would like to delete all rows from table A that are not exist in table B.
In order to do it I use session.Delete(query) as follows:

```
Session.Delete<A>("FROM A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT vpg_id FROM B)");
```

I get the following error:

```
NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: vpg_id of: A [FROM A WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT vpgid FROM B)]
```

I tried also doing it using HQL as follows:

```
Session.CreateQuery("DELETE A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT vpg_id FROM B)").ExecuteUpdate();
```

and get this Exception:

```
    NHibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: IdentNode vpg_id [DELETE A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT vpg_id FROM B)]
```

Comment: Do you actually have a **property** named `vpg_id` in your `B` class (violating all .net guidelines) or are you trying mix a column name there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try aliasing your classes (from NHibernate reference : http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)

```
from A as aClass 
where aClass.id not in ( 
    select bClass.vpg_id from B as bClass
)
```

or try exists

```
from A as aClass 
where not exists ( 
    select bClass.vpg_id from B as bClass where aClass.id = bClass.vpg_id
)
```

Comment: The delete is working for me but it takes too much time: what is the best way to delete many records from table A that not exists in table B. the amount of records that in table B can be more than 50000 and the amount of records to be deleted can be also more than 50000

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it only by using CreateSQLQuery with SQL native:

```
const string deleteSql = @"DELETE FROM CheckpointStorageObject WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from CheckpointToProtectionGroup WHERE CheckpointToProtectionGroup.checkpoint_id = CheckpointStorageObject.id)";
Session.CreateSQLQuery(deleteSql).ExecuteUpdate();
```

I couldn't use CreateQuery since CheckpointToProtectionGroup table is an association table that has 2 references to 2 different table. AS a result NHibernate could not resolve CheckpointToProtectionGroup.checkpoint_id property (even when I used aliases) since checkpoint_id column only exist in database but doesn't exist in CheckpointToProtectionGroup class.

If you use CreateSQLQuery inside a transaction which contains others HQLs which called before CreateSQLQuery and may influence your native SQl - you should call to session.flush() before calling to  CreateSQLQuery.